# How to fix: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonNull' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework

```
// Model Class
public class User
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public Address? Address{get; set;} // issue when Address is null
}

public class Address 
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}


// DB Context Class
public class MongoDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> User { get; init; }

    public static EPCMongoDBContext Create(IMongoDatabase database) =>
        new(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EPCMongoDBContext>()
            .UseMongoDB(database.Client, database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName)
            .Options);

    public EPCMongoDBContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToCollection("user");
    }
}

// Code to Retrieve User
var item = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FirstName == "Scott");
```

**retrieving User object when Address is null throws exception. Not sure how to prevent unable to cast exception?**

Tried [BsonIgnoreIfNull] no help.

Error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonNull' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'.'

Comment: If you can provide a minimal reproducible sample, you could create a Jira item under https://jira.mongodb.org/

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/EF-95 created JIRA.